# C# Progressbar: How many sandwiches on the right side?

Tags: c#, wpf

I need help with the following; I'm making a little "game/simulator" that lets you enter a number (of sandwiches that you drop) and then click on a start button. When you do this a progressbar, which starts on 50% and can be min 0 and max 100, shows how many will fall on the wrong side (butter- side) and how many on the right side. I was thinking that when a sandwich falls on the WRONG side, the progressbar will be <50 and for each sandwich that falls on the wrong side, the progressbar will move down 5%. For each sandwich that falls on the right side, it will move 5% up from 50%. So the odds are 50%.

So if I enter 40 (sandwiches), how do I get the progressbar to move so that some will be on the right side and some on the wrong based on my odds? Right now all I'm getting is either "Amount on the right side: 1" or "Amount on the wrong side: 0", no matter what number I enter in my textbox.

```
    private void btnStart_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Random odds = new Random();
        prgsbrScale.Value = 50;
        int sandwiches = int.Parse(txtSandwich.Text);
        sandwiches = odds.Next(2);

        if (sandwiches == 1)
        {
            txtResultOfAmountOnRightWrongSide.Text = $"Amount on the right side: {sandwiches}";
            prgsbrScale.Value += 5;
        }
        if (sandwiches == 0)
        {
            txtResultOfAmountOnRightWrongSide.Text = $"Amount on the wrong side: {sandwiches}";
            prgsbrScale.Value -= 5;
        }
    }
```

Comment: why only 5%? I dont understand your logic.

Comment: This is very confuse. And you are mixing some concepts here. And some vars should be global.

Comment: I know that I'm missing some concepts, hence why I'm asking :) Does it matter how many % it moves?  I need a progressbar, which starts on 50% because the sandwich can fall on one or the other side. If I put 403 sandwiches I want it to show how many fell on the wrong/right side. I just don't understand how to do that.

Comment: But is not clear at all what do you need, and less what are you asking.

Comment: Wek, yes it matters, is what are you asking in the topic. If you put 2 wrong and 3 right, how much progressbar do you want a show? Use a practical example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a loop to run the simulator.

```
private void btnStart_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Random odds = new Random();
    int sandwiches = int.Parse(txtSandwich.Text);

    // Run the simulation of dropping n-sandwiches
    int sandwichesRight = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < sandwiches; i++) {
        sandwichesRight += odds.Next(2);
    }
    int sandwichesWrong = sandwiches - sandwichesRight;

    txtResultOfAmountOnRightWrongSide.Text = $"Amount on the right side: {sandwichesRight}, Amount on the wrong side: {sandwichesWrong }";
    // Slide value represents percent on right side.
    prgsbrScale.Value = (int)((sandwichesRight / (float)sandwiches) * 100);
}
```